# File system implementation on Nand Flash returns Volume error, Mount Failed

Tags: cortex-m, keil, rtos

i am using keil uV4 and the keil RTX kernel on LPC1788 controller. Using EMC peripheral of LPC1788, i have interfaced the Parallel Nand flash ICK9F1G08U0C. The Init, PageRead, PageWrite & BlockErase functions are working. 
But when i try to implement the FlashFile system on Nand flash, the function finit() returns 0x02 (Volume Error. Mount Failed). I could not get any document describing the solution of the error.
Dont know what further steps to take to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same environment as yours and it all works fine. Did you format it?

Comment: The fformat returns 0x01 - IO Error. IO/driver initialization failed, or there is no media, or media initialization failed.
Which means that the some function is trying to access the IC but is unable to do so. possibly not returning "RTV_NOERR". i gave break points but could not figure out which function is returning the error.

Comment: the PageRead, PageWrite, Init & BlockErase functions are working properly if i use them individually.

Comment: It should be a low-level format. The code will look like the following:-        

            services.clock.get_time(time);
            std::snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "N0:%08X /FAT32 /LOW", time);
            fsret = fformat(cmd);

Comment: fformat("N:/LOW_EB"); ?? Do you have a C equivalent code or can you tell me what is to be done, i'll do the same in C.
Are we to implement Fat32 file system on Nand flash??

Comment: There is a Fat32 file system from Keil. For detail you can contact them.

Comment: i tried this **err = fformat("N0:%08X /FAT32 /LOW");** but of no use

Comment: Dear Leon, I am very new to nand flash memories (and none of my colleague have done anything like this before). hence i request you to kindly elaborate few basics queries.
_Can we implement flash fs on Nand flash (as on spi flash) or do we have to use Fat12/16/32 file system?_

Comment: 'static void cmd_format (char *par)
{
  char *label,*next,*opt;
  char arg[20];
  U32 retv;

  label = get_entry (par, &next);
  if (label == NULL)
  {
    label = "KEIL";
  }
  strcpy (arg, label);
  opt = get_entry (next, &next);
  if (opt != NULL)
  {
    if ((strcmp (opt, "/FAT32") == 0) ||(strcmp (opt, "/fat32") == 0))
 {
      strcat (arg, "/FAT32");
    }
  }

  /* Format with Label "KEIL". "*/
  if (fformat (arg) == 0)
  {
    printf ("Formatted with label %s\n", label);
  }
  else
  {
      printf ("failed.\n");
  }
}'
This is the example function of LPC2470, the best i could get.

Comment: That was the first time we uses it as well. Our goal is very clear at that time, we want to use FAT32. So we jump to hook it up directly. We did have some issue with the finit(). It sometimes return 1, 2 or 4. Then we figured out that funinit need to run before powering off the device. And if that does happen a fformat can save it.

Comment: Thank you leon for the help. The example code of LPC2470 (ARM7) is now modified for CortexM3. Its working.